# DB::insert - returns no error, yet no inserts result from statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have created a backup of a given table using the following raw queries:

```
DB::statement("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS answers_bup");
DB::statement("CREATE TABLE answers_bup AS TABLE answers");
```

The `answers` table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE answers
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  user_id uuid NOT NULL,
  survey_id uuid NOT NULL,
  question_id uuid NOT NULL,
  answer character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
}
```

Now, in order to restore a single row, from the `answers_bup` table to the `answers` table. I wrote the following `DB::insert`:

```
$void = DB::insert("INSERT INTO answers
                SELECT
                '?'::uuid AS id,
                '?'::uuid AS user_id,
                '?'::uuid AS survey_id,
                '?'::uuid AS question_id,
                answer,
                created_at,
                updated_at
            FROM
                answers_bup
            WHERE
                id='?'::uuid", [
    $newId,
    $user_id,
    $survey_id,
    $question_id,
    $answer->id
]);
```

Basically, I only need to copy over three fields from the `answers_bup` table - `answer`, `created_at` and `updated_at`. The others, have to be assigned new values, hence the above statement.

When I run this code fragment, I get no errors. Yet, the insert does not happen. The `answers` table remains empty.

Could anyone help me understand what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try `DB::statement()`, or `DB::table('answers')->insert('...')`